# ANTLR4 - Lexer is consuming too many tokens

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, ebnf

I'm working on a language parser for a little-known constructed language. Its BNF specification is [here](http://www.jfcarter.net/%7Ejimc/guaspi/conclusn.html).

Based on the given BNF, I've come up with the following in ANTLR4:

```
grammar guaspiParser ;

 WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;

// actual grammar here

discourse : (unit)* ;
unit : sentence | nonsentence ;
nonsentence : senstart down1 sentend ;
sentence : senstart (preargs)*? sentend ;
sentend : EOF ; // phrase down1 after1 | phrase ;
senstart : sametone (prefix | primitive) ;

pred : (prefix | primitive) ;
preargs : pred | down1 after1 '/' 'fi' preargs | down1 after1 down1 'fi' '/' args1 | args0 ;
after1 : after1 down1 'fi' '-' after1 | after1 '-' 'fi' down1 after1 | afterargs ;
afterargs : phrase0 afterargs | phrase down1 afterargs | phrase ;

args4 : phrase '!' 'fu'? | phrase0 args4 ;
args3 : phrase up1 | phrase down1 args4 | phrase0 args3 ;

args2 : phrase '!' 'fu'? | phrase down1 args3 | phrase0 args2 ;
args1 : phrase up1 | phrase down1 args2 | phrase0 args1 ;
args0 : (prefix | primitive) compound (prefix | primitive) | down1 args1 | down1 primitive ;
phrase0 : phrase sametone | phrase down1 args1 ;
phrasew : primitive phrasew | primitive ;
phrase : prefix args0 phrase | phrasew ;

// lexer (morphology) stuff here

up1 : '/'  ;
down1 : ('!' | '|')   ;
sametone : '^'   ;
compound : ('-' | '=')   ;

primitive: WORD ;
prefix: FRAG ;

fragment LETTER : [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:#] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
fragment CHAR : (LETTER | DIGIT ) ;
FRAG : CHAR CHAR CHAR?;
WORD : CHAR CHAR CHAR CHAR+ ;
```

However, I feel like the lexer is consuming too many characters; Here's what it produces on an example sentence,

```
^:i !tara /vme -crw !kseo ^vu -tum !kfor ^fe -fnau
```

[image: Parse tree]

What leads me to believe it's a greedy lexer problem is that the debug trace reports things like:

```
line 1:45 no viable alternative at input '!kfor^fe-'
```

What is the problem - what am I missing and/or not doing?

Granted, I am very new to ANTLR; so any tips and pointers would definitely be appreciated. I feel like it's a lot easier than I'm making it to be!

Comment: A few pointers...(1) the lexer does not "consume" tokens. It consumes characters and produces tokens. (2) Your grammar name should just be `guaspi`. The "standard" people have adopted is to append "Parser" to the grammar name only in a "parser grammar", a split grammar. You don't have a split grammar here because you have both lexer and parser rules in the grammar. (3) Use `[a-z:#]` instead of `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:#]`. (4) As Mike points out below, always print out the tokens produced by the lexer when developing a grammar.

Answer (score 2):

If I dump your token stream, I get:

```
[@0,0:0='^',<'^'>,1:0]
[@1,1:2=':i',<FRAG>,1:1]
[@2,4:4='!',<'!'>,1:4]
[@3,5:8='tara',<WORD>,1:5]
[@4,10:10='/',<'/'>,1:10]
[@5,11:13='vme',<FRAG>,1:11]
[@6,15:15='-',<'-'>,1:15]
[@7,16:18='crw',<FRAG>,1:16]
[@8,20:20='!',<'!'>,1:20]
[@9,21:24='kseo',<WORD>,1:21]
[@10,26:26='^',<'^'>,1:26]
[@11,27:28='vu',<FRAG>,1:27]
[@12,30:30='-',<'-'>,1:30]
[@13,31:33='tum',<FRAG>,1:31]
[@14,35:35='!',<'!'>,1:35]
[@15,36:39='kfor',<WORD>,1:36]
[@16,41:41='^',<'^'>,1:41]
[@17,42:43='fe',<FRAG>,1:42]
[@18,45:45='-',<'-'>,1:45]
[@19,46:49='fnau',<WORD>,1:46]
[@20,50:49='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:50]
```

No sign of a greedy token.

Error messages:

```
line 1:30 no viable alternative at input '!kseo^vu-'
line 1:26 extraneous input '^' expecting {<EOF>, '!', '|', FRAG, WORD}
line 1:45 no viable alternative at input '!kfor^fe-'
line 1:41 extraneous input '^' expecting {<EOF>, '!', '|', FRAG, WORD}
```

corresponds with token stream:

```
[@8,20:20='!',<'!'>,1:20]
[@9,21:24='kseo',<WORD>,1:21]
[@10,26:26='^',<'^'>,1:26]
[@11,27:28='vu',<FRAG>,1:27]
[@12,30:30='-',<'-'>,1:30]
```

If I examine your grammar, there is no rule that accounts for a `!` (`down1`) followed by a `WORD` token followed by the other tokens in this sequence (you’ll probably be able to find a path up to the ‘-‘ token and then a dead end).

You may find it handy to generate the “railroad” diagrams to try to follow this through ( it took me a bit just to find where the second token (of this section) could follow the first.